# strong name dll searching

Tags: .net

If a dll is strong assembly in which paths the CLR will try to find the strong assemblies.
 For example for the private assembly CLR will try to find the directory in which exe is  present or checks any subdirectory exists with the same name as the exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the path the executable is run from will be used to find referenced assemblies.  Strongly-named asssemblies (having a strong name key) can be installed to the global assembly cache (GAC) and the .NET executable can reference the assembly from the GAC too.